# Error while importing library "modin" in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ray, modin

```
import modin.pandas as pd
```

I am importing modin.pandas library in my windows 10 machine but getting error

> "AttributeError: module 'ray' has no attribute 'utils'"

Anything missed while installing modin library?

Comment: As you are using `ray` are you importing it? Eg `import ray
ray.init(plasma_directory="/path/to/custom/dir", object_store_memory=10**10)
# Modin will connect to the existing Ray environment
import modin.pandas as pd`?

Comment: Also, prior to the question above, did you install Ray? `pip install modin[ray]`? This will pip install modin dependencies and Ray to run on Ray

Comment: @GonçaloPeres龚燿禄 thanks for the reply, Yes I have installed like "pip install modin[ray]" but still same problem, import ray - no errors, but only errors on import modin.pandas

Comment: And as for the first question, are you importing ray?

Comment: @GonçaloPeres龚燿禄 No I am not importing ray, but I tried with importing ray and same issues in both the cases

Comment: As I don't have much time for debugging right now, I suggest you to share your issue [here](https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues).

Comment: It seems you got incompatibility between ray and modin. Could you try uninstall both and then `pip install ray==1.1` finally install modin via `pip install modin`

Answer (score 3):

> "AttributeError: module 'ray' has no attribute 'utils'"

It looks like, you should be able to fix the issue if you just install the 1.1 version of ray, by doing the following :

```
pip install ray==1.1
```

The modin.pandas creators haven't release support for versions of ray greater then 1.1.

Here is the discussion thread on github :
https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues/3059

Comment: This _is_ the version that works for me today.  So, it should have got the bounty in first place.  But I voted for the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68155285/8854526) by @Ann.Zenn as it's more generalized... and should withstand the test of time-- in case, say, when `ray` upgrades its support for versions beyond `1.1` !

Comment: @ParthaD. Glad it helped. Don't worry about the bounty :)

Answer (score 2):

I followed the below steps to install Modin using Ray execution engine. Install Modin dependencies and Ray to run on Ray -

```
pip install modin[ray]
```

Also, please customize your Ray environment for use in Modin using the below commands.

```
import ray
ray.init()
import modin.pandas as pd
```

Please check out Intel Distribution of Modin (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/distribution-of-modin.html#gs.14j7r0) and Modin official page (https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for installation issues and to accelerate pandas workflow on Intel architectures.

Answer (score 1):

Check which version of `ray` you have; `ray.utils` used to be called `ray.experimental`.

You'll either need to upgrade version of the module you're using that has `ray` as a dependency *(meaning the module currently uses the out-of-date version of `ray`)*, or downgrade the version of the `ray` *(to be compatible with the module you're using)*.

Comment: It's true I changed the version of quite a few modules... which apparently caused the error (previously it was working fine). And at some point of time (I don't remember) it got all right again.  At present, I have `pandas==1.1.5`, `modin==0.8.3` and `ray==1.1.0` ...just to assist someone with my use case, if at all that's necessary !

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. For me I uninstalled the existing modin and ray package from my instance and then restarted the kernal and then used the following command:

```
pip install modin[ray]
```

It then worked for me. If you are running it in google Colab you can find more information [here](https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues/881).

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid the OP addressed that this didn't work. See their comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67345646/error-while-importing-library-modin-in-python-3-6/68175591#comment119038763_67345646